# AWS Lambda unzip gzip file w/o saving the file on local

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gzip, aws-lambda, unzip

I'm trying to get a file from a S3 bucket (.gzip) and unzip it to another bucket. I couldn't find a way to do it without saving the file on local (my PC). Is there a way to 'save' the file on Lambda and unzip it directly on S3? Thank you!

Comment: Did you try to uncompress as byte stream and write to s3?

Comment: As byte stream, can I play with the file inside the zip before uploading it to S3? I have a gzip with a log and I need to format it as csv before uploading.  Don`t really want to upload the log, download and format then reupload. (using fast-csv for formating)

Comment: Yes, fast-csv accepts stream. Thanks for your tip. :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a lambda code for example ([gist](https://gist.github.com/johnib/20248744716dfe37cc053559541778f9)):

```
let path = require('path');
let aws = require('aws-sdk');
let s3Client = new aws.S3();
let zlib = require('zlib');
let s3s = require('s3-streams');

const output_bucket = "stackoverflow-bucket";

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

    event.Records.forEach(record => {
        const params = {
            Bucket: record.s3.bucket.name,
            Key: record.s3.object.key
        };

        const isGzip = path.extname(params.Key) === ".gz";
        let readStream = s3Client.getObject(params).createReadStream();

        readStream = isGzip ? readStream.pipe(zlib.createGunzip()) : readStream;
        writeStream = s3s.WriteStream(s3Client, { Bucket: output_bucket, Key: path.basename(params.Key, ".gz") });

        // begins the actual streaming
        readStream.pipe(writeStream);

        writeStream.on('end', () => {
            callback(null, `Handled ${JSON.stringify(params)}`);
        });
    });
};
```

Note that this code uses a 3rd party library for streaming bytes to S3 (which is not natively supported by the Node.JS SDK).

For that, the documentation page [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-create-deployment-pkg.html), which describes how you should package your lambda before uploading it to AWS.

You can set a S3 event to trigger your lambda whenever a new file is put to your source bucket:

[image]

Comment: I managed to save the file on the server with [os](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html). Thank you for your answer.

Comment: This is not a good approach as it works only for small files. Do you know what's the storage limitation you have on lambda? You better off with my solution, your call.

Comment: Btw if that answered your question please mark it :). Thanks

Comment: I'm handling a 2MB csv file (~10k lines). I don't think it will get bigger than that but I'll keep your answer in mind :).